# C -> Possible to reference struct from itself?

Tags: c, struct

I'm a java programmer and am new to C style struct, I have a struct that contains a function that contains a switch case:

```
typedef struct
{
 char name;
 void myFunction()
 {
  switch(?)
  {
   case "y": break;
   default:  break;
  }
 }
}AXIS;
```

I was wondering if there is a way I can have the "?" passed to my switch be AXIS.name for whatever name I assign.

For example if I have

```
AXIS Y={"y"}
```

i want `Y.myFunction()` to call case `y`.

I'd appreciate any help in this matter, thank you.

Comment: That is not C, that is C++, or maybe something else.

Comment: And yes you can do it, but then you have to give the structure a name (e.g. `typedef struct AXIS { ... } AXIS;`). And yes, you can give the structure the same name as the type-alias. Although, with C++ you don't need to make type-alias of structures, as they are types in themselves, so `struct AXIS { ... };` will work just as well.

Comment: You cannot use strings with `switch` in C. Only integers.

Comment: And *if* you are programming C, then you should throw away the tutorial or book you are currently reading, because apparently it's no good.

Comment: @user694733 in his case though he could switch case or `char[4]` like 'abcd', since it can be represented as an integer

Comment: Will `name` change with time?

Comment: @FélixCantournet: A `long`, if `sizeof(long) == 4`. Likely on most modern systems, though there are some with all types 64 bits, and similar fun.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I rolled back the C tag. This is a question about C, OP is only confused, considering his/her Java background.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has several problems:

- `char name` is a single character, not string.
- You cannot have struct member functions in C.
- `switch` doesn't work with strings.

Let's fix the structure first:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[10]; // Maximum allowed string is 9 characters.
} AXIS;
```

Then the function:

```
void myFunction(AXIS * self) { // You need to pass the object pointer explicitly
    if(strcmp(self->name, "y") == 0) { // Compare string with strcmp
         // String was equal to "y"
    }
}
```

And finally the call:

```
int main(void) {
    AXIS y = {"y"};
    myFunction(&y); // Give address of an object to function
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing C, just put a function pointer in that struct, and at initialisation time set the right one:

```
void function_y(){...}
void function_z(){...}

typedef struct{
  void (*myFunction)();
} AXIS;

AXIS a = {function_y};
```

If the name change over time, define an `enum` to *enumerate* all the possible values `name` could take, instead of using a `char`. Then you will need to add a parameter to `myfunction` so as to get the value in `name`:

```
typedef enum {
  Y,
  Z
} AxisName;

typedef struct AXIS {
  AxisName name;
  void (*myFunction)(AXIS *);
} AXIS;

void AXISfunction(AXIS *axis){
   switch (axis->name){
     case Y:
     /*... */  
}

AXIS a = {Y,AXISfunction};

void foo(){
  a.myFunction(&a);
}
```

(this is basically the poor man OOP in C).

In C++, you may follow the same principle (using an `enum`), but you don't need that extra parameter, nor do you need to use a function pointer:

```
struct AXIS {
  AxisName name;
  void myFunction(){
      switch(name){
        case Y: //...
        //... 
      }
   }
};
```

Of course you may use inheritance and overloading (like in Java) to avoid using switches.